# Developing local WP-site with remote data - Can't connect?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp, remote-server

I'm trying to develop a WordPress site locally with a remote database. I'm one of three developers, and we have the whole site on GitHub, so we commit and push changes there. But we all want to be able to see changes locally before we commit, and that's where I've run in to trouble.

I use MAMP and have it all set up, but when I fill in the details to the remote DB, it doesn't connect.

Can someone help me here? :)

Comment: Does the remote server allow remote connections?

Comment: I am checkout that out as we speak... but i have created databases there before and connected them to websites hosted elsewhere erlier so i guess?

Comment: Is it that the server isn't allowing the connection (likely at a firewall level), or that the username you're trying to connect with doesn't allow logins from your remote IP.

Are the other developers able to connect to the remote server?

Comment: Nope, same issue for all of us. We get the error saying the details don’t match or the server is down...